# How can you make a flags enum serialize its combination values numerically in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

Suppose you have a flags enum in C#:

```
[Flags]
public enum FlagsEnum
{
    One = 0x1,
    Two = 0x2,
    Four = 0x4,
    ...
}
```

If you run this through standard JSON or XML serialization, `FlagsEnum.One` will be serialized as the string `One`, `FlagsEnum.Two` as `Two`, etc.  If you wanted to change it to have the values serialized as the integers `1`, `2`, etc., a typical solution for enums in general is to use the `EnumMember` attribute or `XmlEnum` attribute.

The problem is that with a flags enum, you're expecting several numerical values to be used that aren't specifically declared.  Googling around doesn't seem to turn up much a solution for that scenario.  So how would you get something like this to be serialized to integer values that aren't simply powers of 2, showing things in the serialized form like `23`, `15`, etc.?

**EDIT**

Part of what I'm looking for is a way to specify this within the enum itself, without adding any extra values to the enum or properties to other types.  There is a question in my mind, however, whether that is actually possible (basically speaking).

Also the main type of serializer that this is really coming up with at the moment is `DataContractSerializer`.  However typical, standard JSON stuff would also be applicable to this question, and the goal is to avoid changing out the serializers themselves and using anything customer or off the beaten path.  (Attributes and stuff would be good, if it can be done that way.)

Comment: The only possible way to do this as part of the Enum without extra properties etc. is attaching some sort of serialization hint attribute to the property, or setting up some configuration for the serializer. This then depends on which serializer you are using (e.g. `DataContractJsonSerializer` vs Json.Net `JsonSerializer`). What are you using to do serialization?

Comment: You may be trying to solve a problem you don't need to solve.  As long as your enum is marked with `[Flags]` both `XmlSerializer` and Json.NET will serialize bitmasked values correctly.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBSPWY, which shows that the XML generated will be `<FlagsEnum>One Two Four</FlagsEnum>` and the JSON will be `"One, Two, Four"`.

Comment: @dbc is totally correct, just double checked the serialization

Comment: @dbc The preference would be for it to serialize that as `7`, to have it work right out of the box.

Comment: @ASpirin Undelete your answer, and I'll at least upvote it.  This is asking for numerical values instead.

Comment: *The preference would be for it to serialize that as `7` right out of the box.* -- each serializer is going to behave differently; there is no general answer for all serializers other than to use a surrogate property as in @ASpirin's answer.  E.g. Json.NET serializes enums as integers by default.  If you are seeing them serialized as strings then somewhere you must be applying [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).

Comment: JSON gives me `{"foo":6}` so I removed JSON from answer

Comment: @dbc Thanks, yeah, I got mixed up for just a minute.  I re-edited the question to show that I was seeing it with `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialization out of the box allows to save and restore flaged enum values:

```
<foo>Two Four</foo>
```

but with string values in XML

To save it as int interpretation you can make an int property and serialize it instead

```
[XmlIgnore]
public FlagsEnum foo{get;set;}
public int bar
{
    get{ return (int)foo;}
    set{ foo = (FlagsEnum)value;}
}
```

In that case your XML will have int values and the object will have full enum data

for `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` works an option with `IXmlSerializable` interface implementation, but it's a bit too excess for a big classes

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name == "foo")
        {
            foo = (FlagsEnum)reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
        }
    }
}

public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteElementString("foo", ((int)foo).ToString());
}
```

Comment: There's no way to specify it within the enum itself?

Comment: Don't thing it will be in enum, such a things could be in Serializers, it depends on serializer. E.g. you can make override serialization to have it as int in XMl.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be just creating a separate `int` property for serialization.

```
public class DTO
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public FlagsEnum Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int Prop1Serialize { 
       get { return (int)Prop1; }
       set { Prop1 = (FlagsEnum)value; }
    }
}
```